# How Do I Merge A Temporary Map Onto A Permanent Map So That I Can Record Several Items Of The Same Key?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have two maps where the key is based off of the length of the word. Whenever there is a word with the same amount of length, I want it added to that key.

I want to do this by using the `map.merge()` function, however, after looking at the documentation I am unsure how to do so. I tried looking at other resources, but not many have helped.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();


String[] wordsSplit = doc.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < wordsSplit.length; i++) {
    int key = wordsSplit[i].length();
    Map<Integer, String> tempMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    tempMap.put(key, wordsSplit[i]);
    //merge here
    map.merge(key, map.keySet(), map.get(key) + ", " + wordsSplit[i]);  
}
```

Edit: This question is different because here I am trying to figure out how to map in the context of merging the temporary map onto the the old map.

For instance, this means if there are several items that share the same key, then it would more turn out as: key: `"Car, bar, Tar"`

Comment: Why not using a multi map?

Comment: This is part of a larger assignment. I've spent a while now trying to figure out the merge function, but and I've figured out this is how it should be, but I just don't understand what I should put for the merge args. Furthermore, I know how to do this with using a map of lists, which seems more intuitive, but the merge call iteration is throwing me off.

Comment: you're misunderstanding `merge`. It still takes key and value + a merge function for the case that the key already exists: `for(int i = 0; i < wordsSplit.length; i++) {
    String word = wordsSplit[i];
    int key = word.length();
   
    //merge here
    map.merge(key, word, (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal + ", " + newVal);  
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a merge function to concat words with same length, seperated with `", "`;

```
BiFunction<String, String, String> mergeFunction = (i, j) -> {      
    return i + ", " + j;
};
```

Then `map.merge(key, x, mergeFunction);` merges the elements of `wordsSplit` array according to their length. Below `key` is length of word, `x` stands for `wordsSplit[i]`

```
Stream.of(wordsSplit).forEach(x -> {
    int key = x.length();
    map.merge(key, x, mergeFunction);
});
```

Or you can just past the body of merge function `(i, j) -> { return i + ", " + j; }` into `map.merge()` instead of defining `mergeFunction` seperately:

```
Stream.of(wordsSplit).forEach(x -> {
    int key = x.length();
    map.merge(key, x, (i, j) -> { return i + ", " + j; });
});
```